# How to implement ShouldChangeCharacters in Monotouch?

Tags: xamarin.ios, uitextfield

I have a UITextField where I want to change the characters using ShouldChangeCharacters delegate method. But when  I use the textField obj, it says that does not match with UITextFieldChange...
How should I do it in Monotouch?

Answer (score 10):

Here is an example of forcing all caps:

```
    textField.ShouldChangeCharacters = (textField, range, replacementString) => 
    {
        using (NSString original = new NSString(textField.Text), replace = new NSString(replacementString.ToUpper()))
        {
            textField.Text = original.Replace (range, replace);
        }
        return false;
    };
```

I think it should be what you need.  I tend to use Lambda expressions always, that way you don't need to even know the delegate type, parameters types, etc.  I let C# type inference do the work.